# Oracle 11g - log directory

Tags: oracle, authentication, logging, oracle11g, logout

I am using Oracle 11g in window 10. I want to know the default path for login/logout logs. I am to use this for generating alert for suspicious login.

Comment: This depends on how you configured auditing.

Answer (score 3):

You can determine that path through the query below

```
select value
  from gv$parameter 
 where name = 'background_dump_dest';
```

*where `g` at the beginning of `gv$parameter` is used for RAC type databases, and that letter can be removed and used as `v$parameter`*

From the query, you may have a value like

`....\app\oracle\admin\<dbname>\adump` where `.aud` files,

`....\app\oracle\diag\rdbms\<dbname>\<dbname>` where `alert_<dbname>.log` or `.trc` files may be found, depending on your configuration during the `DB` installation.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I run your query and the result is d:\app\ajaykumargupta\diag\rdbms\orcl\orcl\trace now when i go to this location i have so many files (.trm/.trc) and it was not having human readable log.

Comment: @AjayGupta you're welcome. They sjould have some human readable parts too :) You may consider the other edited suggestions also.